# Visual Studio Online integration with CodePlex

Tags: integration, azure-devops, codeplex

Is there a way to integrate a Visual Studio Online repository with a CodePlex project in a way that when I update code in Visual Studio Online it reflects and updates the CodePlex project?

Answer (score 6):

No, this is currently not possible in an automatic way.

But as a workaround you could setup both systems to use Git as the repository type and use a local git repository to sync between both remote repositories.

To do so create a new local repository using

```
git init
```

Then add the two remotes

```
git remote add codeplex https://git123.codeplex.com/project
git remote add vso      https://account.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection/_git/Repo
```

Now you can work in your local git repository and when you want to push the data to either Visual Studio Online or CodePlex you can push the data using:

```
git push codeplex master
git push vso master
```

Both git repositories will be cryptographically the same.

If you want to show your CodePlex user name in `codeplex`, you'll need to setup your git user name to that.

Comment: This setup is quite easy to script indeed.